# Get average of column parts in pivot table

Tags: python, select, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table.

[image: pivot_table1]

[image: pivot_table]

Which I created by doing this:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['day_of_week','date'],values=['dt_hours'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

The problem is that I do not get how I can get the average of `dt_hour` for all days.

So I succeed in taking for example the average of: `[0.564167, 2.835278, ... , 1.119444, 8.287778]`

I do that by: `table['dt_hours']['Friday'].mean()`

But I need all the days' averages in a list.

So: 
`Friday average = 15.69706 
Tuesday average = 7.56426
Wednesday average = 6.84077
etc.`

And this I want to put in a dataframe or dictionary, as I want to make a plot of this.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the following works with you. I assumed a simplified dataframe with dummy data which is in your format in the following answer. `dow` here corresponds to `day_of_week` and `hours` correspond to `dt_hours` in your case. Day is presented by the first letter. i.e. f -> Friday.

We first reset the index in order to use boolean indexing. And then find the `hours` values for each day and loop through the resulting *Series* to find the average.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df = pd.DataFrame({"dow": ["f", "f", "t", "t", "w","w"], 
"date": ["3/7","2/3","6/7","5/6","1/2","4/2"],
"hours": ["21","34","56","78","32","88"]})

table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['dow','date'],values=['hours'],aggfunc=np.sum)

t=table.reset_index()

avg_arr = []

print set(t.dow)
for day in set(t.dow):
    vals=t[(t.dow==day)]['hours']
    total = 0
    c=0
    for i,r in vals.iteritems():
        c+=1
        total+=float(r)
    avg = total/(c)
    avg_arr.append(avg)


print avg_arr
```

Comment: Thank you! The part with the pivot table and then reset index is the part which I was missing. So you really helped me!